# What is the maximum application filesize for Blackberry App World

Tags: blackberry, filesize, max

We are planing to program an application for Blackberry and wondering if there is a maximum App size.
Searching the App World there were just very small Apps.
Our App will have hundreds of Images and Audiofiles. It will have about 40 to 50 MB.
Is this possible for Blackberry?

thx for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible -- but not practical.  First consider that many people install an app OTA (over the air) and even on a fast 3G connection it's going to take a LONG time to download 40-50MB.  Another factor is limited memory on devices.  Applications have to be stored and run from the on-device flash memory, which is quite limited (32MB on older devices, 64MB or 128MB on newer devices).  Apps, emails, contacts, etc. all take up space on the main memory so this space is at a premium.  Basically even if people DO have enough space on their device to accomodate an app that size, chances are unless it's a really killer app they're not going to install it due to the size.

One alternative to bundling your resources with your app is to load them dynamically at runtime as they are needed.  Host them on a webserver somewhere, and load them over the network from the app as needed.  If the user has an SD card installed, you could cache data there since they typically have much more space than the onboard memory.

Comment: caching and loading it dynamically from the network will not work, because it is a dictonary like app and the user will use it also outside its homecountry and costs would explode for the user then.
so it is not possible to store the app on the external SD card?
or is there a possibility to store resources on the external SD and the app on the internal flash memory?
thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: The app itself must live entirely in the onboard memory - but if you can find another way to get the content onto the SD card then you can access it from the SD card from the app.  For example some apps such as Slacker have a program you install on your PC that downloads  music and stores it on the SD card (via USB) for the program to access.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer doesn't quote any sources. According to this official BB document, the maximum size is on the order of 14MB. If you want more, you must download it to the SD card after it's installed.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/The-maximum-size-of-a-BlackBerry-7-or-earlier-smartphone/ta-p/1300209